# value of jquery with autoNumeric textbox into c#

Tags: c#, jquery

I have 4 textboxes, in 3 of them can numbers be insert and the 4th will output the sum.
Now I'm trying to get the sum to c# as an integer, so I try it with an hidden field "HF_ProjekteGK".

This is my jquery code:

```
 <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.11.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/autoNumeric.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<%= TB_ProjekteGK.ClientID%>').autoNumeric({ aSep: '.', aDec: ',', aSign: ' €', pSign: 's', aPad: false });
        $('#<%= TB_ProjekteAK.ClientID%>').autoNumeric({ aSep: '.', aDec: ',', aSign: ' €', pSign: 's', aPad: false });
        $('#<%= TB_ProjekteMAE.ClientID%>').autoNumeric({ aSep: '.', aDec: ',', aSign: ' €', pSign: 's', aPad: false });
        $('input:text[id$=TB_ProjekteSumme]').autoNumeric('init', { aSep: '.', aDec: ',',     aSign: ' €', pSign: 's', aPad: false });
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var textBox1 = $('input:text[id$=TB_ProjekteGK]').keyup(projekte);
        var textBox2 = $('input:text[id$=TB_ProjekteAK]').keyup(projekte);
        var textBox3 = $('input:text[id$=TB_ProjekteMAE]').keyup(projekte);

     function projekte() {
            var value1 = textBox1.autoNumeric('get');
            var value2 = textBox2.autoNumeric('get');
            var value3 = textBox3.autoNumeric('get');
            var projekte = add(value1, value2, value3);
            $('input:text[id$=TB_ProjekteSumme]').autoNumeric('set', projekte);


            $("#HF_ProjekteGK").val(projekte);

        }
     function add() {
            var sum = 0;
            for (var i = 0, j = arguments.length; i < j; i++) {
                if (IsNumeric(arguments[i])) { sum += parseFloat(arguments[i]); }
            }
            return sum;
        }
        function IsNumeric(input) {
            return (input - 0) == input && input.length > 0;
        }
    });  

     </script>
```

This runs and $("HF_ProjekteGK").val(gesamtsumme); shows the right sum.

Now I'm trying to catch the value to the hidden field:

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int test = Convert.ToInt32(HF_ProjekteGK.Value);
    }
```

Here I get an exception that the input string has no correct format becaue it is null. How can I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried old way? `Request.Form["HF_ProjekteGK"].ToString()`

Comment: don't work: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`